# sql query not supported

Tags: sql, subquery

Table:

```
first_col         second_col
78                 g1
79                 g2
754                g1
34                 g2
67                 g1
```

When this query is executed:

```
SELECT T1.* ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM Tab1 T2 WHERE T2.first_col=T1.first_col GROUP BY 
second_col) THEN 'include' ELSE 'exclude'  END new_col FROM Tab1 T1;
```

But this subquery is not supported

Thanks!

Comment: `GROUP BY` and subqueries are tricky.  Please provide an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Is `first_col` unique in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Correlated subqueries are not supported on Redshift as you can see and there are reasons for this which isn't important now.  The issue is that you need to rewrite the query.  At first blush this looks straight forward in this case.

The key is to change this to a join replacing this clause "WHERE T2.first_col=T1.first_col" with the JOIN ON clause.  Here's a untested cut at this rewrite to demonstrate how this could look (your exact case could tweak this):

```
SELECT T1.* ,
    CASE WHEN T3.first_col is not NULL THEN 'include' ELSE 'exclude'  END new_col 
FROM Tab1 T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT first_col 
    FROM Tab1 T2 
    GROUP BY second_col 
    HAVING count(1)<3 ) T3
ON T3.first_col=T1.first_col
;
```

By changing to a left join we can still test when there is no match between T2 and T1 on first_col.  Hopefully this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if *any* "second cols" appear fewer than 3 times for matching "first col".  To do this, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`, but like this:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       COALESCE(tt1.new_col, 'exclude') as new_col
FROM Tab1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT 'include' as new_col
      FROM (SELECT first_col, second_col, COUNT(*) as cnt
            FROM Tab1 tt1
           ) tt1
      HAVING MIN(cnt) < 3
     ) tt1;
```

However, in any database, I would recommend doing this using window functions:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when min(cnt) over (partition by first_col)
             then 'include' else 'exclude'
        end) as new_col
from (select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by first_col, second_col) as cnt
      from tab1 t1
     ) t1;
```